# Trigger to delete a field and add a prefix to other field

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

In my collection there is a document that can receive three fields, but I need to keep only two according to the values informed, for example I have fields A, B and C, depending on the value I do not need to record field B or C. I also need that A prefix is written in field A. I followed this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?hl=pt-br) and created the function where I can read the fields, but I couldn't change or delete them. I used the onCreate event.

See my sample:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.testFields =
  functions.firestore.document('documentos/{documentoId}/ocorrencias/{ocorrenciaId}').onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    const ocorrencia = snapshot.data();
    //I can read the values
    fieldA = ocorrencia.fieldA;
    console.log('Field A: ', fieldA); //'Teste'
    fieldB = ocorrencia.fieldB;
    console.log('Field B: ', fieldB); //5
    fieldC = ocorrencia.fieldC;
    console.log('Field C: ', fieldC); //6
    if(fieldB > FieldC){
      //the C field does not need to be recorded
      prefix = 'B';

    }else{
      //the B field does not need to be recorded
      prefix = 'C';
    }
    //now I need to record the prefix next to FieldA
    //my FieldA should look like this: 'CTeste'
  });
```

Comment: Hello Deivis, welcome to Stack Overflow, could you edit the post and add some code so the community can check what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
if (fieldB > FieldC) {
    //the C field does not need to be recorded
    prefix = 'B';
    ocorrencia.fieldC = null;
} else {
    //the B field does not need to be recorded
    prefix = 'C';
    ocorrencia.fieldb = null;
}
//now I need to record the prefix next to FieldA
//my FieldA should look like this: 'CTeste'
ocorrencia.fieldA = prefix + fieldA;
functions.firestore.collection('ocorrencias').update(ocorrencia);
```

NOTE: The way your code is currently structured, it is performing 2 write calls to every record you create, one on the actual creation of the record, followed by the update call I suggested. This could generate some overhead on your system moving forward, or at least increase your number of write operations, which could be significant on billing, I would suggest you perform this check not in a cloud function, but in your front end.

Comment: @Deivis Átila, has the solution offered addressed the issue you were facing?